# v0.8 LinkToken.sol error. ParserError: not found: File not found?

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity

I get these version import errors when I tried to execute

```
brownie run scripts/deploy_lottery.py`
```

I'm learning `blockchain` with the help of `freecodecamp.org`'s youtube video.

it's working fine with the older version.

```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

  import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/ERC677Token.sol";
  import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from 
  "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/StandardToken.sol";
```

error with the V0.8

So, this is my code

[image: This is the LinkToken.sol file's error part and error in the terminal when I run]

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

    import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol";
    import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from 
    "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/StandardToken.sol";

    contract LinkToken is linkStandardToken, ERC677Token {
        uint256 public constant totalSupply = 10**27;
        string public constant name = "ChainLink Token";
        uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
        string public constant symbol = "LINK";

        function LinkToken() public {
            balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        }
```

```
    terminal....--> 
      ~/b/first/smartcontract-lottery  brownie run scripts/deploy_lottery.py     
                               
       Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

       New compatible solc version available: 0.8.11
       Compiling contracts...
       Solc version: 0.8.11
       Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
       EVM Version: Istanbul
       CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

       ParserError: Source "/Users/mohameduzair/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix@2.3.0/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> contracts/test/LinkToken.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


       ParserError: Source "/Users/mohameduzair/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix@2.3.0/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/StandardToken.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> contracts/test/LinkToken.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/StandardToken.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is "brownie-config.yaml" file

[image: This is "brownie-config.yaml" file]

```
   dependencies:
     - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.0
     - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2
     - smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix@2.3.0
   compiler:
     solc:
       remappings:
         - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.0"
         - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2"
         - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix@2.3.0"
   networks:
     default: "development"
     development:
       keyhash: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc"
       fee: 250000000000000000
     rinkeby:
       vrf_coordinator: "0x6168499c0cFfCaCD319c818142124B7A15E857ab"
       eth_usd_price_feed: "0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419"
       link-token: "0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709"
       keyhash: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc"
       fee: 250000000000000000
       verify: True
     mainnet-fork:
       eth_usd_price_feed: "0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419"
   wallets:
     from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could add link to video on youtube.

Comment: errors show `"File not found"` with path to some file - first you could check if you have this file on disk. Maybe new version use differnt names.

Comment: this the youtube video I'm following...                    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=20996s

Comment: error show problem with file `/Users/mohameduzair/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix@2.3.0/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol` - did you check if you have it ? Maybe it has different path - ie `v0.8.11` instead of `v0.8`, etc.

Comment: this video is almost 6 months old. In this time modules could change, etc.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I fixed the bug. Now it's working properly :)

Comment: what was the problem? How did you fix it ? You could describe it as answer. Maybe it will be useful for other users.